# Android 13, API 33 - random crashes in native library

Tags: android, api, crash, native

I'm facing random crashes when using API 33 in our native library.

The process ID mentioned in the crash details belongs to our APK but the thread ID does not. It appears that the crash is inside a thread internally used by Android.

Some weird lines in the log are:

```
12763 12783 D vulkan  : searching for layers in '/data/app/~~YSD64u2g1Ks8H7PwCekvsg==/<our_appid>-BNptLXg5dYX-N0-R8cw6FQ==/lib/arm64'

12763 12783 D vulkan  : searching for layers in '/data/app/~~YSD64u2g1Ks8H7PwCekvsg==/<our_appid>-BNptLXg5dYX-N0-R8cw6FQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a'

12763 12783 I scudo   : Scudo ERROR: corrupted chunk header at address 0x200006f73ea6f90
```

Is there anyone else facing similar issues? Does anybody have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: where you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi Brijesh, Using cmake instead of ndk helped